# How to find roots of a cubic through their sum and products?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

So I have a cubic polynomial and the sum and products of roots are as follows:
$x+y+z=-3$, 
 $xy+yz+xz=-6$,  $~xyz=18$
So i know this can be done through system of  simultaneous equations but dont know how, i know the answer but can someone show me the process?

BTW, the answers are $- 3,6^{1/2},-6^{1/2}$

Comment: You can write down the cubic from what you are given. The rational root theorem enables you to isolate the integer root. Then you have a quadratic to solve. In general, with these data, you have to solve the cubic.

Comment: I also know the cubic equation, only wanted to know if we can find the roots by solving these equations simultaneously.

Comment: Solving the simultaneous equations is simply equivalent to solving the cubic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). In particular, with an initial coefficient of $1$, i.e.,

$$P(s) = s^3 + a_2 s^2 + a_1 s + a_0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

has $a_0 = -xyz = -18$, $a_1 = xy+yz+xz = -6$ and $a_2 = -(x + y + z) = 3$. Thus, you have

$$P(s) = s^2 + 3s^2 - 6s - 18 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

You could use this to solve for the individual roots using the [Cubic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) formula.

Update: As discussed in the question comments and the comments below, it's often easier & faster, especially for simpler type cubic equations (e.g., all coefficients are integers) to first try other methods to determine one root, e.g., by factoring by grouping (see [How to Factor by Grouping](https://www.wikihow.com/Factor-by-Grouping) for details) or using the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). If you do determine a root, you can then reduce your sets of equations to a quadratic, so you can then use the [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to get the other $2$ roots. If you can't find an initial root, note the suggestion above of using the cubic function formula will always work.

Comment: *You could use this to solve for the individual roots using the Cubic function formula.* --- Or you could just factor by grouping: $s^3 + 3s^2 - 6s - 18 = s^2(s+3) - 6(s+3) = (s+3)(s^2 - 6),$ whose roots are found from $s+3 = 0$ and $s^2 - 6 = 0.$

Comment: Ummmm... Is it possible to find roots directly from these equations thats i have shared?, any way to solve them simultaneously perhaps?... Because i know the rational roots test and vietas formula but dont want to solve it through its cubic equation.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, you could group them as you stated, but you would either need to know $-3$ is a root or be able to see you can group it in this way.

Comment: I am also talking about the latter, can you help me find a pattern for grouping?

Comment: *be able to see you can group it in this way* --- [factor by grouping](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22factor+by+grouping%22) (also called [factor by pairs](https://www.google.com/search?q="factor+by+pairs")) is a standard method in attempting to factor a polynomial.

Comment: @HaadZahid Unfortunately, due to the non-linear aspects, it's not generally particularly easy to solve for these equations. As [Mark Bennet](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2906/mark-bennet)'s comment indicates, if you can find any one root, you can then get a quadratic to solve. For that first root, you can use the rational root theorem, i.e., check the factors of $xyz = 18$ to find that $-3$ is a root. You can then get your other $2$ roots relatively easily.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I did a quick look at https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/quadratic/Quadratic_Equations.faq.question.232486.html and I believe this is similar, although possibly sometimes easier, but also at other times harder, to using the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). However, in many cases, there are no rational roots, so it likely won't help, unless you can find & group non-rational factors.

Comment: [I certainly know about the rational root test](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Dave+L+Renfro%22+%22rational+root+theorem%22&filter=0), and it's what I'd try after spending a minute or so exhausting standard methods. In older pre-calculator texts, essentially every polynomial you needed solutions for or to factor (e.g. in applying partial fractions to integrate, in setting the derivative equal to zero to find critical points, etc.) would be solvable by using the rational root test for "reduction of order". (FYI, I have to go off-line now.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$x^3-x^2(x_1+x_2+x_3)+x(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)-x_1x_2x_3=x^3+px^2+qx+r$$

Answer (score 0):

These can be solved simultaneously by progressively eliminating variables. Start with
$$
z = -3-x-y
$$
to get
$$
3y+y^2+3x+x^2+xy =6
\\ 3xy+x^2 y+y^2x =-18.
$$
Multiply the top through by $x$ and subtract the two equations to get
$$
x^3 +3x^2 = 6x + 18
$$
and we end up with the cubic equation anyways.

Comment: I dont know why, but that was hilarious and yes its true i also did that but blamed it on bad grouping .. Now i think that it can only turn out this way.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are the three roots, then they satisfy the equation

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=0\tag{1}$$

Expand the left-hand-side

$$x^3-(x_1+x_2+x_3)x^2+(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)x-x_1x_2x_3=0$$

The given on the three roots, i.e. $x_1+x_2+x_3=-3$, 
 $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=-6$ and $x_1x_2x_3=18$, just happen be the three coefficients, respectively. So, plug in their values to get

$$x^3+3x^2-6x-18=0\tag{2}$$

Since (1) and (2) are equivalent, We rewrite (2) below in the same product form as (1)

$$(x+3)(x-\sqrt{6})(x+\sqrt{6})=0\tag{3}$$

which can be verified straightforwardly by expanding. Then, compare (3) with (1), we are able to identify the three roots as $x_1-3$, $x_2=\sqrt{6}$ and $x_3=-\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the system

$$\begin{cases}x+y+z=a,\\xy+yz+zx=b,\\xyz=c\end{cases}$$ and try to solve it.

Multiplying the second by $z$,

$$xyz+z^2(x+y)=bz.$$

Then using the first and the second to eliminate $x,y$,

$$c+z^2(a-z)=bz$$ or

$$z^3-az^2+bz-c=0$$ and you are back at the cubic equation !